# How to limit value orientation in rank Android

Tags: android, orientation

How to limit value orientation in rank

from
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29

```
values[0]: azimuth, rotation around the Z axis.
values[1]: pitch, rotation around the X axis. Default (-180to180)
values[2]: roll, rotation around the Y axis.  Default (-90to90)
```

I want to limit values[1] from default to (-90to90). How to do?

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  synchronized (this) {

    switch(event.sensor.getType()){
      case Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION: {
      com.app.labylinthii.Global.setXaxis(Float.toString(event.values[0]));
      com.app.labylinthii.Global.setYaxis(Float.toString(event.values[1]));
      com.app.labylinthii.Global.setZaxis(Float.toString(event.values[2]));
      break;
      }
      case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER: {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Thank You.

Comment: Why? You need 360 degrees to compute the orientation.